# When the MsgBox function in ms access returns -1 value in vbYesno

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2003

```
If [Due_date] < (Date - 1826) Then 
j = (MsgBox("This invoice is long overdue, isn't it. Is it correct?
     Do you want to save it?", vbYesNo, "Due date < 5 yrs from Today")) = 7 

If j = -1 Then DoCmd.GoToControl ("Due_date"): GoTo 9999
```

When will j have -1 value.
I have tried to look every where, not able to find it.

Answer (score 0):

You should stick to the constants - and rewrite a little for readability:

```
If [Due_date] < DateAdd("yyyy", -5, Date) Then 
    If MsgBox("This invoice is long overdue, isn't it. Is it correct? Do you want to save it?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Due date < 5 yrs from Today") = vbNo Then
        DoCmd.GoToControl "Due_date"
    Else
        GoTo 9999
    End If
End If
```